# Clone Tensorflow.js Loaded Model

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a model, `hand-shape`, that is sequential and stateful.
This means that on every inference, it depends on the output of the previous inference, in sequence.

I would like to run this model for both the left and the right hand, independently.

My current working solution, is to:

```js
leftModel = await tf.loadLayersModel('hand-shape.json')
rightModel = await tf.loadLayersModel('hand-shape.json')
```

However, this has a flaw of loading the model twice from disk, instead of once.

Is there a way to load the model, then clone it?

```js
leftModel = await tf.loadLayersModel('hand-shape.json')
rightModel = cloneModelSomehow(leftModel) // don't reload from disk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with `tfjs`

```js
// Load model from disk
leftModel = await tf.loadLayersModel('hand-shape.json');

// Clone model
const modelData = new Promise<ModelArtifacts>(resolve => leftModel.save({save: resolve as any}));
rightModel = await tf.loadLayersModel({load: () => modelData});
```